# Converting Twitter's created_at date using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, date, format

I am using a combination of PHP/JavaScript to pull in Tweets from Twitter and trying to convert the created_at response to just show the month and day.

My JSON response for the created_at date `data[0].created_at` returns this:

```
Wed Oct 15 21:30:47 +0000 2014
```

And I would like to convert it to this:

```
Oct 15
```

Is it possible to do this in JavaScript? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//split it into an array
//splice and only keep the two words that contain date information
//join it with a space
'Wed Oct 15 21:30:47 +0000 2014'.split(' ').splice(1,2).join(' ');
//in case you need the year too
//get the year by going to the last array index and join that too
var split = 'Wed Oct 15 21:30:47 +0000 2014'.split(' ');
var date = split.splice(1,2);
var year = split[split.length-1];
date.push(year);
date = date.join(' ');
```

Comment: You could use the JS Date function but that would require a dictionary of month names and get the month name by finding the month number in the Date function and then converting it to Month string, it's neat but the long way around...

Comment: That's what I was thinking I was going to have to do, this is much simpler. Thanks again!